# Две сетевые карты и две сети - нужен интернет только из одной

Tags: сеть, vpn, доступ

Есть две локальные сети, по сути это разные VPN. Есть ПК под управлением WinXP с двумя сетевыми картами. В Обоих сетях есть доступ к сети Интернет. Задача такова - обеспечить на данном ПК функционирование обоих сетей (возможность получать доступ к ресурсам обоих сетей), а доступ в Интернет осуществлять только одной из них

Answer (score 1):

А не будут в таком варианте ВСЕ пакеты идти через указанный интерфейс? М.б. стоит добавить два постоянных маршрута:
***route add -p x.x.x.x mask *.*.*.* <ip сетевой, у которой нужна локалка>
route add -p 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 <ip второй сетевой>***
мне кажется, что-то такое должно быть. Соответственно вместо х.х.х.х - нужная подсеть.

Comment: они и так добавлены, посмотри у себя на шминдоусе)

Comment: ага. только вот у меня есть машинка на которой надо было настроиться именно так, как написал @ant1 . И до тех пор, пока не были поправлены постоянные маршруты до вида приведенного мной в ответе, сеть сходила с ума. Написал то, что у меня работает уже пару лет без сбоев)

Answer (score 0):

*route add 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 "ip нужного вам шлюза" "нужный интерфейс"*

profit ?!